# How to identify and convert partial date

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have diversity partial date formats, for instance mm/yy, MMM yyyy and ect.
How to identify and  convert partial date to format yyyy-mm???

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems: 1) How to identify the right pattern for each date, 2) Only month and year don't make a date, the day is missing. This means DataWeave date functions will not work.

1) You can use described on the KB article https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Parsing-variable-format-date-strings-using-DataWeave of using regular expressions to parse each format to see which match, and encapsulate it into a function. The article is for Mule 3, so if you are using Mule 4 (you should mention the Mule version in the question for better results) then you will need to migrate the example.

2) You can concatenate a dummy date to the month-year to convert it to a full day before trying to use a pattern to convert to the expected output pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can't do this type of coercion without a day as part of the date, so I think the best option is to add a dummy day value and then coerce to whatever format you need. Just remember to default for nulls as trying to concatenate to a null will error out your script. For example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun formatDate(date: String): String = 
    (date ++ "/01") as Date {format: "MM/yy/dd"} as String {format: "yyyy-MM"}
---
formatDate(payload)
```